# How to expand the video container smoothly as it comes to viewport in Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-directives

I have to make a webpage very similar to this [one](https://www.wealthsimple.com/en-ca/product/cash). I'm using Nuxt for this, I'm facing issues in making the video expand & shrink in the exact same way.

I've tried to replicate the issue on [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tap3px?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/App.vue). The directive is not working correctly actually. I want to achieve exactly the same transition as soon as the video enters into the view-port.

Code of the custom directive -

```
export default {
  directives: {
    inView: {
      isLiteral: true,
      inserted: (el, binding, _) => {
        const isInView = () => {
          const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
          const inView = (rect.width > 0 && rect.height > 0 && rect.top >= 0 &&
            (rect.bottom + 100) <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight));
          if (inView) {
            el.classList.add(binding.value);
            // window.removeEventListener('scroll', isInView);
          } else {
            el.classList.remove(binding.value);
          }
        };
        window.addEventListener('scroll', isInView);
        isInView();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `scroll` listener, use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/IntersectionObserver) to track when the element comes in or out of view. The following observer creates an `IntersectionObserver` with a 30% threshold, adding the `binding.arg` value as a CSS class to the element when in view:

```js
export default {
  directives: {
    inView: {
      mounted(el, binding) {
        const threshold = 0.3 // trigger callback when element is 30% in view
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
          const elem = entries[0]
          if (elem.intersectionRatio >= threshold) {
            el.classList.add(binding.arg);
          } else {
            el.classList.remove(binding.arg);
          }
        }, { threshold })
        observer.observe(el)
        binding.instance.observer = observer
      },
      unmounted(el, binding) {
        binding.instance.observer.disconnect()
      },
    }
  },
}
```

Then use the directive on the `video-wrapper` element to animate (where `scale` is the animating class):

```html
<div v-in-view:scale class="video-wrapper">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-i1qi6h?devtoolsheight=33&file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: I have literally copied your code and pasted it, but it is not working. Although it is working on the StackBlitz. Actually even the logs which I have added inside `mounted()` and `unmounted()` are not firing

Comment: Is it because I'm using Nuxt js?